# Adding an Moving Average component in GAMs model

Tags: r, time-series, gam, mgcv, autocorrelation

I have a simple model, for which the residuals exhibit auto-correlation beyond one order.

I have a simple model for which I want to include a moving average component up to a third order.

My model is this:

```
m1<-gamm(y~s(x,k=5), data = Training)
```

the time series properties of y, shows that this follows an ARMA(0,0,3)

because the residuals of `m1` are auto-correlated I want to include a moving average component in `m1`

The answers for similar questions talk only about an AR(1) process, which is not my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `corARMA(p, q)` function in package *nlme* for this. `corAR1(p)` is just a special case function as there are certain efficiencies for that particular model.

You have to pass `q` and/or `p` for the order of the ARMA(p, q) process with `p` specifying the order of the AR terms and `q` the order of the MA terms. You also need to pass in a variable that orders the observations. Assuming you have a single time series and you want the MA process to operate at the entire time series level (rather than say within a years but not between) then you should crate a `time` variable that indexes the order of the observations; here I assume this variable is called `time`.

Then the call is:

```
m1 <- gamm(y ~ s(x, k = 5), data = Training,
           correlation = corARMA(q = 3, form = ~ time))
```

When looking at the residuals, be sure to extract the normalised residuals as those will include the effect of the estimated MA process:

```
resid(m1, type = "normalised")
```

Comment: Do you know where I can have a look at what kind of transformation the package does to account for auto-correlation ? All documentation I found describe the functions. Don't want want that. I am interesting for a mathematical exposition.

Comment: Your best bet is to read the section of the book that the nlme package supports: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98882 Essentially this is estimating a correlation matrix for the model residuals where the elements of the correlation matrix are given by the estimated ARMA(p,q) process.